# Command denied for table 'session_variables'

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, privileges, sql-grant

After updating mysql version 5.7.8-rc-log, I granted privileges like this:

```
GRANT select ON test_db.* TO 'test'@'host';
```

and getting following error:

> SELECT command denied to user 'test'@'host' for table 'session_variables'

but when I grant privileges like this:

```
GRANT select ON *.* TO 'test'@'host';
```

it works. Can anybody help?

Comment: so what's the problem? "I could not open this locked door, but it opened when I unlocked it"? Uh, no duh?

Comment: I think you screwed up your copy paste, please check your post

Comment: I don't want to grant access to all databases for every user - THAT'S THE PROBLEM.

Comment: both your GRANT syntax seems same, how they are different?

Comment: My mistake, sorry.
`GRANT select ON test_db.*` vs `GRANT select ON *.*`

Comment: which mysql version you are using

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName

`version 5.7.8-rc-log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the [article1](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=5991741), [article2](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21108), [article3](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/baffling-5-7-globalstatus-variables-issues-unclean-migration-path) related to this issue.
As per these articles, Workaround is setting `show_compatibility_56 = on` in `/etc/my.cnf` and restart mysql server.

MySQL 5.7 introduces a change in the way we query for global variables and status variables: the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.(GLOBAL|SESSION)_(VARIABLES|STATUS)` tables are now deprecated and empty. Instead, we are to use the respective performance_schema.(global|session)_(variables|status) tables.

But the change goes farther than that; there is also a security change.

So non-root user gets:

```
mysql> show session variables like 'tx_isolation';
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'normal_user'@'my_host' for table 'session_variables'
```

**Solutions?**

The following are meant to be solutions, but do not really solve the problem:

- SHOW commands. SHOW GLOBAL|SESSION VARIABLES|STATUS will work properly, and will implicitly know whether to provide the results via information_schema or performance_schema tables.
  But, aren't we meant to be happier with SELECT queries? So that I can really do stuff that is smarter than LIKE 'variable_name%'?
  And of course you cannot use SHOW in server side cursors. Your stored routines are in a mess now.
  This does not solve the GRANTs problem.
- show_compatibility_56: an introduced variable in 5.7, boolean. It truly is a time-travel-paradox novel in disguise, in multiple respects.
  Documentation introduces it, and says it is deprecated.
  time-travel-paradox :O
  But it actually works in 5.7.8 (latest)
  time-travel-paradox plot thickens
  Your automation scripts do not know in advance whether your MySQL has this variable
  Hence SELECT @@global.show_compatibility_56 will produce an error on 5.6
  But the "safe" way of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'show_compatibility_56' will fail on a privilege error on 5.7
  time-travel-paradox :O
  Actually advised by my colleague Simon J. Mudd, show_compatibility_56 defaults to OFF. I support this line of thought. Or else it's old_passwords=1 all over again.
  show_compatibility_56 doesn't solve the GRANTs problem.
  This does not solve any migration path. It just postpones the moment when I will hit the same problem. When I flip the variable from "1" to "0", I'm back at square one.

**Suggestion**

I claim security is not the issue, as presented above. I claim Oracle will yet again fall into the trap of no-easy-way-to-migrate-to-GTID in 5.6 if the current solution is unchanged. I claim that there have been too many changes at once. Therefore, I suggest one of the alternative two flows:

- Flow 1: keep information_schema, later migration into performance_schema
  In 5.7, information_schema tables should still produce the data.
  No security constraints on information_schema
  Generate WARNINGs on reading from information_schema ("...this will be deprecated...")
  performance_schema also available. With security constraints, whatever.
  In 5.8 remove information_schema tables; we are left with performance_schema only.
- Flow 2: easy migration into performance_schema:
  In 5.7, performance_schema tables should not require any special privileges. Any user can read from them.
  Keep show_compatibility_56 as it is.
  SHOW commands choose between information_schema or performance_schema on their own -- just as things are done now.
  In 5.8, performance_schema tables will require SELECT privileges.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I put in /etc/my.cnf in [mysqld] section:

`show_compatibility_56=1`

and it resolved my problem! Thank you @HaveNoDisplayName

Comment: According to [the mysql bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77732) on this matter, it seems that the recommended (??) way to resolve this is to grant the `SELECT` privilege on the master to the replication user, e.g.: `GRANT SELECT ON performance_schema.global_variables TO 'replica_user'@'replica_host';`

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following way, maybe you will get the result.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON bedgeaj_medmax.transactions to 'bedgeaj_root'@'%'  IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

(OR)

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: As root I have grant option, so it is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

GRANT SELECT ON performance_schema.session_variables TO stevejobs;
GRANT SELECT ON performance_schema.session_status TO stevejobs;

Comment: Please format your code as code by adding 4-space indentation to it

Answer (score -1):

### For accessing GLOBAL|SESSION VARIABLES try with command in MYSQL:-

$ GRANT ALL ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';

$ GRANT ALL ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';

### If it is not working then you should try(It only provide SELECT permission to 'sonar' user for all DATABASES):

$ GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'sonar'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';

$ GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'sonar'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';

### It provides permission to sonar user to access all the databases with all the privilege SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE (ALL possible moves on DB.

$ GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'sonar'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';

$ GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'sonar'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';

Comment: it is not my downvote, but do you know how dangerous wildcards are? Even if the op had them, you should advise them of the danger

Comment: @Drew its already mentioned that "It provides permission to sonar user to access all the databases with all the privilege SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE (ALL possible moves on DB)" within bold caption.so i think it easy go with with option or not with acces to particular  user name.

Comment: my bad. My screen layout is reversed colors due to eyestrain. thx. I guess reviewing up to 500 a day does this